# Generating 4 digits SMS confirmation code

Tags: c#, sms

I need to generate simple, 4 digits confirmation SMS code, which based on given information, e. g. username, or birthdate, whatever. So, for two identical inputs, I need two same output codes.

I can't store this code in database.

I'm writing in C#, and have been thinking about `GetHashCode` method, but he is highly not recommended to use anywhere. Maybe some hashing, but they have much more that 4 character string.

How can I generate such code?

Comment: You're trying to hash millions of possible values into a 4-digit code (which means only 10000 possible values)? How will you handle collisions?

Comment: A confirmation code being deterministic makes no sense whatsoever.

Comment: @whatsisname if it's deterministic, maybe other ideas, how to generate that code? I can't store it in database.

Comment: @VincentSavard I don't care about collisions. Sounds rude, but that's application not for cryptographical purposes.

Comment: use TOTP with something like a 30 minute resolution versus 30 seconds.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time-based_One-time_Password_Algorithm

Comment: What is the threat that you're trying to protect against? Who is the audience for this confirmation code? Does it matter if other people guess the code?

Comment: Threat - confirm that user understands information that he has put into form.  Audience - simple users with mobile phones. Absolutely doesn't matter.

Comment: Why does it have to be deterministic?

Comment: @MatthewWhited interesting idea, I'll try it.

Comment: @VincentSavard because, I can't store it in database.

Comment: If it absolutely doesn't matter, then just use the date. No need to give the appearance of security.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just take the pieces of info you need, concatenate them together into a string, then hash it with a cryptographic hash function. Take the bottom 4 digits of the hash and call it a day.

Comment: wouldn't it be slow?

Comment: @YuriyN.: it will be sufficiently fast for all practical purposes.

Comment: Ok, seems legit.

Comment: Why bother with a cryptographic hash? This is ultimately security by obscurity, and a simple hashcode is just as obscure as a cryptographic hash -- perhaps moreso, because an attacker might try common crypto-hash algorithms first. I much prefer your comment on the original question.

Comment: @kdgregory: cryptographic hash should yield a somewhat more flat digit distribution, but I agree it's not critical and it's mostly "might as well"

Answer (score -1):

> based on given information, e. g. username, or birthdate, whatever. So, for two identical inputs, I need two same output

Why?  The point of most SMS confirmations is to confirm the identity of the person initiating a particular action.  To this end, it makes *no difference* what's in the code you send.  So long as the receiving user types in what you sent, that's all you need.  Also, generating this code deterministically based on other [personal] data is a potential security hole.

> I can't store this code in database.

SMS is *not* a synchronous protocol.

Just because you *sent* a message doesn't mean that it's been received or even that the user has their phone charged up and switched on at the time.  It may be several minutes before the user is in possession of the code you sent and is ready to type it back in.

Where *else* are you going to store it whilst you're waiting??

GetHashCode returns a unique value for every .Net object within a running application but, as soon as that object goes out of scope and is garbage collected, that value is gone and cannot be recovered.
Unless you store it somewhere.

Comment: I need simple SMS confirmation, that user agreed with the information given, how else can I do that? That's the key point: "Where else are you going to store it whilst you're waiting??", I don't need to store it, I need to compute it deterministically.

Comment: You ask why it needs to be deterministically computable from user info. The second part of your answer explains exactly why: so that you don't have to store it in the database.

Comment: "GetHashCode returns a unique value for every .Net object within a running application but, as soon as that object goes out of scope and is garbage collected, that value is gone and cannot be recovered." It can sorta be recovered, if you know what the 'value' of the object was. If you can produce a new object that is equals() to the old, then the new one will have the same hashcode as the old one (or at least it should, otherwise you will have other problems).

Comment: If the derivation is deterministic, then the confirmation code will /always/ be the same.  If the code is intercepted or becomes known to someone other than the intended recipient, then it can be reused by said miscreant, thereby opening a hole in your security system.  What's wrong with sending and storing (in the short term) a randomly generated code?

Comment: @whatsisname: Not necessarily.  Both GetHashCode() and Equals() are /virtual/ methods; different classes can implement different behaviour/ return different values from these methods.

Comment: @PhillW.: the overrider is then responsible for implementing the right behavior: http://stackoverflow.com/a/371348/8159 otherwise the class will fail to function in a dictionary or possibly other collections as well.